# Cannot deploy reports on localhost/reports

Tags: sql-server-2008, virtual-machines, windows-xp

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2, Sql Server Reporting Services(SSRS) on an xp virtual machine.. I have created a report and am trying to deploy it... but getting this error...

```
The specified report server URL http://localhost/Reports could not be found. 
Verify the syntax of the URL and that the report server exists.
```

I went to see my "services".... SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) is "started", but SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) is not. When I try to start it, it says

> windows could not start the sql server on local computer error code 10048

I tried to go in cmd and tried

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe -sMSSQLSERVER
```

I get this, 
Server Error: 17058, Severity: 16, State: 1.

can someone please help me...

Comment: Thanks David... I did try to uninstall and reinstall and now it says database engine error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10048 means "Address already in use."

This means that you couldn't start SQL Server, because SQL Server Express was still running. Stop SQL Server Express, then start SQL Server.

Comment: Sweet lord... thanks Michael... I thought of doing that... but I had both of them running on my local machine... so I assumed, sql server express had to be running as well in my vm... thank you sir